# Plotting sin(x)/(x) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, numerical

I am having issues plotting sin(x)/(x) correctly. Specifically when x = 0, returns NaN in Matlab. However, when applying L'Hôpital's rule the actual value is y = 1. My question is how can I go into the y matrix and change the of NaN. What I brainstormed for possible approaches is creating a For loop to scan the y matrix for NaN.

```
x = [-10:0.5:10]
y = sin(x)./(x);
plot(x,y), axis([-10 10 -1 1.5])
```

Plot of sin(x)/x

[image]

Comment: you can either use the `piecewise` function, or make a function of your own which uses a switch statement, treating x = 0 as a special case.

Comment: If you are feeling golfy :-P `f = @(x)(sin(x)+~x)./(x+~x)`

Comment: Do you just  want the connected plot or the values of `y` without `NaN` as well?

Comment: Use the [`sinc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/sinc.html) function if you have the Signal Processing toolbox.

Answer (score 3):

The function that you're looking for is [`fplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fplot.html).

```
x = [-10, 10];        %Range
y = @(x) sin(x)./x;   %Function
fplot(y, x);
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to your original question how to access the nans in general, simple 
    y(isnan(y)=something should work. So in this case,

```
x = [-10:0.5:10]
y = sin(x)./(x);
y(isnan(y))=1; 
plot(x,y), axis([-10 10 -1 1.5])
```

Answer (score 0):

In C  I've used this:

```
#define SINC_EPS (1e-6)
// for small x, 
//  missing sinc terms start with pow(x,4)/120, and value close to 1, so negligeable in doubles    
double  sinc( double x)
{       return fabs(x) < SINC_EPS ? 1.0 - x*x/6.0 : (sin(x)/x);
}
```

Comment: How is C relevant to MATLAB?

Comment: @excaca The approximation is relevant to the problem, and I thought posting working code would reduce typos.

Comment: I'm sure working C code will be super helpful for writing MATLAB code, a language that shares essentially no syntax. Please see the [relevant meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290046/if-the-question-is-specifically-about-a-certain-language-is-an-answer-in-anothe)